# Undefined method 'title' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am following railsspace book but when i trying edit show and eliminate a post owner (chapter 15) I get: error message

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass
```

follow extact:

```
1: <div class="post">
2: <div class="post_title">
3:  
4: <%= sanitize post.title %>
5: <% unless hide_edit_links? %>
6: <span style="float:right">
7: <%= link_to_unless_current 'Mostrar', blog_post_path(post.blog, post) %> |
```

Ruby 1.9.2 
Rails 3.1.3

The controller, views and routes is as follow:

Controller: posts_controller

```
  # Encoding: UTF-8
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper :profile
  before_filter :protect, :protect_blog
  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.xml
  def index
    #Recheck implement paginate for Rails 3.1.3
    #@pages, @posts = paginate(@blog.posts)
    @posts = @blog.posts
    @title = "Administración del Blog"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.rhtml
      format.xml { render :xml => @posts.to_xml }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.xml
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @title = @post.title
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.rhtml
      format.xml { render :xml => @post.to_xml }
    end
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
    @title = "Nuevo post"
  end

  # GET /posts/1;edit
  def edit
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @title = "Edit #{@post.title}"
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.xml
  def create
    @post = Post.new(params[:post])
    @post.blog = @blog

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.duplicate? or @blog.posts << @post
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to blog_post_url(:id => @post) }
        format.xml  { head :created, :location => blog_post_url(:id => @post) }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @post.errors.to_xml }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /posts/1
  # PUT /posts/1.xml
  def update
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
        flash[:notice] = 'Post was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to post_url(:id => @post) }
        format.xml { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @post.errors.to_xml }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.xml
  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.xml { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private

  # Ensure that user is blog owner, and create @blog.
  def protect_blog
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:blog_id])
    user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    unless @blog.user == user
      flash[:notice] = "That isn't your blog!"
      redirect_to hub_url
    return false
    end
  end
end
```

View: index

```
<h2>Sus Blog Posts</h2>
<p class="edit_link">
<%= link_to 'Agregar nuevo post', new_blog_post_path %>
<%= "| Pages: #{pagination_links(@pages)}" if paginated? %>
</p>
<%= render :partial => "post", :collection => @posts %>
```

View: post

```
<div class="post">
<div class="post_title">

<%= sanitize post.title %>
<% unless hide_edit_links? %>
<span style="float:right">
<%= link_to_unless_current 'Mostrar', blog_post_path(post.blog, post) %> |
<%= link_to_unless_current 'Editar', edit_blog_post_path(post.blog, post) %> |
<%= link_to 'Eliminar', blog_post_path(post.blog, post),
:confirm => 'Deseas eliminar este post?', :method => :delete %>
</span>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="post_body"><%= sanitize post.body %></div>
<div class="post_creation_date">
Publicado <%= time_ago_in_words post.created_at %> ago
<% if post.updated_at != post.created_at %>
<br /> Modified <%= time_ago_in_words post.updated_at %> ago
<% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

In this view , i has triying put @ in the variable post =@post, but it not work
Routes

```
Expression::Application.routes.draw do

  get "email/remind"

  get "avatar/index"

  get "avatar/upload"

  get "avatar/delete"

  get "community/index"

  get "community/browse"

  get "community/search"

  get "faq/index"

  get "faq/edit"

  get "spec/index"

  get "spec/edit"

  get "profile/index"

  get "profile/show"

  get "user/index"

  get "user/register"

  get "site/index"

  get "site/about"

  get "site/help"

  get "user/login"

  get "user/logout"

  get "user/edit"

  get "user_mailer/welcome_email"

  post "user/register"

  post "user/login"

  post "user/edit"

  post "spec/edit"

  post "faq/edit"

  post "community/index"

  post "community/search"

  post "avatar/upload"

  post "email/remind"

  resources :blogs do
    resources :posts
  end

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  root :to => 'site#index'

  # match'', :controller => 'site', :action => 'index', :id => nil
  resources :user
  match '/register', :to => 'user#register'
  match '/about', :to => 'user#about'
  match '/help', :to => 'user#help'
  match '/login', :to =>'user#login'
  match '/edit', :to =>'user#edit'
  match '/user/welcome_email', :to => 'user#create'

  #resources :profile
  #match '/show', :to => 'profile#show'

  # Install the default route as the lowest priority.
  match ':controller/:action/:id'
  match 'profile',  :to => 'profile#show', :as => "profile"
  match 'hub', :to => 'user#index', :as => 'hub'

  ##Change Route pagina 343
  # You can have the root of your site routed by hooking up ''
  # -- just remember to delete public/index.html.
  match '', :controller => 'site', :action => 'index', :id => nil
###

#match'', :controller => 'user', :action => 'about', :id => nil
#match'', :controller => 'user', :action => 'help', :id => nil

# See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
end
```

ApplicationStacktrace

```
app/views/posts/_post.erb:4:in `_app_views_posts__post_erb__1793130860277527745_40556500'
app/views/posts/show.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_posts_show_html_erb__2356198700875868089_40643800'
app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:23:in `show
```

Answer (score 0):

After deleting your code is trying to redirect to `posts_url`.
However I do not see that in your routes.  btw you can also do `rake routes` at the command line to see what your routes are.
I think you need to add a get for `posts/index` although I would really look to try and use [RESTful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) which would clean up much of your routes.

Comment: the complete code this in https://gist.github.com/37400e3e78bbf6628667 @Michael Durrant

Comment: Yes I look looked through it.  Please type `rake routes` at the command line from in the applications root directory and post the output.

Comment: I looked more.  posts is nested with blogs.  So you need to either redirec to the blogs index page, or redirect and pass which blog, or add a new line in routes.rb for posts (outside of, but as well as the nested one).  You should also strongly consider changing posts to something like 'comments' as you could run into issues with that being a reserved word somewhere.  I still recommend `rake routes` to see the routes and get familiar with the command and the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@post.title`, instead of `post.title` on line 4 of your template.